# Error when saving HStoreField using Admin: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have a simple model:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    test_store = HStoreField()
```

I edited the migration for this model per the HStoreField [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield).

I have no trouble creating an object with test data `{"foo": "bar"}`, and in the Admin, the field for `test_store` displays the value as such, but when I try to save it with the Admin, I get the following error:

`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Why?

I'm using Django 1.8.3 and Python 2.7.9

Hint: It seems like it's passing the data as `{u'foo': u'bar'}` and running into issues with the JSONDecoder:

```
    def decode(self, s, _w=WHITESPACE.match):

        """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` or ``unicode``

        instance containing a JSON document)

        """

                    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

 ...

        end = _w(s, end).end()

        if end != len(s):

            raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))

        return obj

    def raw_decode(self, s, idx=0):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs due to the fact that in `json.load()` passed a variable of type `dict()`. This [bug is fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/a7b7f27c05244d69a11545261eb3bbd73791b3d2?diff=split) in next django release.
I apologize for my english, i used google translate.